# map() function error: Error: Can't convert a two-sided formula to a function

Tags: r, purrr

I've got the coefficients related to some linear mixed models and stored into a list in the following way:

```
models_list_1 <- data_long %>%
  group_by(signals) %>%
  do(fit = lmerTest::lmer(value ~ A*B + (1 |C), data = .)) %>% 
  pull(fit) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) summary(x)$coefficients) %>% 
  setNames(unique(data_long$D))
```

Since I'm interested to reproduce results iteratively into some table, I'm trying running the follwing code

```
models_list_1 %>%  
  map(.x ~broom::tidy() %>%
    flextable::flextable()
)
```

But getting back this error

```
Error: Can't convert a two-sided formula to a function
```

Does anyone know how to correct syntaxis?

Comment: The anonymous function you use in map is not defined correctly. Check the `map` documentation for correct definition. Hint: The left side must be empty.

Comment: So I'm quite new with R. Cannot understand how to fix this

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but I really suggest you use this as an opportunity to learn a bit more about it. The documentation of `map` is really good and there are many examples on how to use the formula syntax in map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the formula with `~` and not with `.x` using `map`:

```
models_list_1 %>%  
  map(
    ~ .x %>% broom::tidy() %>% pull(x) %>% as_tibble() %>% flextable::flextable()
  )
```

Comment: It turns back the following error `Error in x$data[i, j] <- value : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
In addition: Warning message`

Comment: I've just tapped into the example here reported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841042/creation-of-table-from-lists-elements-containing-lsmeans-statistics. I know that the code should me just rehandle but it escapes me how

Comment: `broom::tidy` creates a nested one column data frame which needs to be unpacked with pull() to be passed to `flextable`

Comment: There is also the function `coefficients` to do e.g. `iris %>% lmer(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length + (1|Species), data = .) %>% summary() %>% coefficients()`

Comment: Do `lapply(function(x) summary(x) %>% coefficients())` instead of `lapply(., function(x) summary(x) %>% coefficients()) `